# how to access querystring in ASP.Net MVC View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How do I access the `querystring` value in a View?

Comment: never heard of anyone having the need to do such thing in asp.net mvc, probably you want to access it an Action cuz that's going to be really easy

Comment: Are you sure you need query strings in MVC? Maybe give an example of what you want.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It is not a good design to access query parameters in a view. The view should use the model provided by the controller. So the controller reads query parameters and passes them to the view. If you want to ignore this rule you could always do this in your view:

```
<%= Request["SomeParameter"] %>
```

But I would strongly discourage you from doing so.

Answer (score 25):

In View, you can access it directly. No need to write any code in Controller, though you can.

For example - 
If your querystring has parameter named id, something like ?id=1

Razor syntax:

```
@Request.QueryString["id"]
```

Comment: Error CS0103 The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 14):

In **.Net Core**:

```
@Context.Request.Query["SomeParameter"]
```

Answer (score 8):

I would read the querystring value in your Controller, and then set that value to a property in your ViewBag.  The ViewBag property can then be read in from your view.

e.g:

```
ViewBag.MyQSVal = Request.QueryString["myValue"];
```

Then, in your View:

```
@if(ViewBag.MyQSVal == "something"){ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Darin suggested you should not use Querystring in view. But one thing is you can access Request variable in your view because its Asp.Net and if you access it you have all the functions and member that are present there