# Getting "Id" value from the URL in MVC 4

Tags: c#, url, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.0, routes

My URL is something like,

**`localhost:19876/PatientVisitDetail/Create?PatientId=1`**

I have to retrieve the `PatientId` from the URL and pass it along the request.

I tried,

```
    Url.RequestContext.Values["PatientId"] => System.Web.Routing.RequestContext does not contain a definition for 'Values' and
no extension method 'Values' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Routing.RequestContext'
```

Again I tried,

```
RouteData.Values["PatientId"]  => an object reference is required for the non static field, method
or property 'System.Web.Routing.RouteData.Values.get'
```

**EDIT:**

Based on the Jason's comment below, I tried `Request["SomeParameter"]` and it worked. But, there is also a warning to avoid that.

Any ideas how to avoid this for my scenario ?

My scenario:

There is a `Create` action method in my controller for creating a new patient.

But, I need to go back to the last page,

If  I give something like,

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") 


=> this wont work because my controller action method has the following signature,

public ActionResult Index(int patientId = 0)
```

So, I must pass along the `patientId` in this case.

Comment: Since `PatientId` is a querystring parameter, take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888105/how-to-access-querystring-in-asp-net-mvc-view

Comment: @JasonEvans: Thanks for the link. It worked. But, I also see a warning, that `do not access the url parameters in the view?`. In my scenario, how to avoid that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are effectively circumventing the whole point of MVC here. Have an action which accepts `PatientId` i.e.

```
public ActionResult Create(int patientId)
{
    return View(patientId);
}
```

Then in your view use that value e.g.

```
@model int

@Html.ActionLink("Back", "LastAction", "LastController", new { patientId = @Model })
```

This is the MVC way.

Comment: clean solution. Thanks

Comment: perfect! neat and clean solution I have found here. Thanks! @James

Answer (score 2):

From your controller, you could put the `PatientId` in a `ViewBag` and access it from your View

```
public ActionResult Create()
{

    ViewBag.PatientId = 1;
    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index", new { PatiendId = ViewBag.PatientId })
```